# MVC [HttpPost/HttpGet] for Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using MVC C#.

Can somebody give an example on why one would use

```
[HttpPost/HttpGet]
```

for an Action. How can an active have both - what is the practical use?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Let's say you have a `Login` action which provides the user with a login screen, then receives the user name and password back after the user submits the form:

```
public ActionResult Login() {
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password) {
    // do login stuff
    return View();
}
```

MVC isn't being given clear instructions on which action is which, even though we can tell by looking at it. If you add [HttpGet] to the first action and [HttpPost] to the section action, MVC clearly knows which action is which.

Why? See [Request Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). Long and short: When a user views a page, that's   a GET request and when a user submits a form, that's usually a POST request. HttpGet and HttpPost just restrict the action to the applicable request type.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login() {
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password) {
    // do login stuff
    return View();
}
```

You can also combine the request method attributes if your action serves requests from multiple verbs:

`[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what you are saying and have used it accordingly. From some reading online, I was under the impression that we can use [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] for the same action (not seperated)

Comment: Just tried on MVC4. [HttpGet][HttpPost] does not work, that only accepts GET requests (or whichever verb is written first). However, [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)] does work well.

Comment: @AndreasLarsen: Maybe consider posting a question about that specifically so MS can see it. I'll edit my answer if I can get confirmation it's intentionally.

Comment: I can confirm what AndreasLarsen reported. You must use AcceptVerbs to have 2+ verbs on the method.

Comment: @Kivin I've tested [HttpGet, HttpPost] in MVC5 and it does not work for both verbs. drzaus's answer also confirms that it doesn't work. [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)] does work however.

Comment: Thanks for AcceptVerbs solution. Somehow this works while when I specify [HttpGet] and [HttpOptions] does not

Answer (score 26):

You don't need to specify both at the same time, unless you're specifically restricting the *other* verbs (i.e. you don't want PUT or DELETE, etc).

Contrary to some of the comments, I was also unable to use both Attributes `[HttpGet, HttpPost]` at the same time, but was able to specify both verbs instead.

### Actions

```
    private ActionResult testResult(int id)
    {
        return Json(new {
                            // user input
                            input = id,
                            // just so there's different content in the response
                            when = DateTime.Now,
                            // type of request
                            req = this.Request.HttpMethod,
                            // differentiate calls in response, for matching up
                            call = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name
                        },
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public ActionResult Test(int id)
    {
        return testResult(id);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TestGetOnly(int id)
    {
        return testResult(id);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestPostOnly(int id)
    {
        return testResult(id);
    }
    [HttpPost, HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TestBoth(int id)
    {
        return testResult(id);
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult TestVerbs(int id)
    {
        return testResult(id);
    }
```

### Results

*via POSTMAN, formatting by [markdowntables](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)*

```
| Method    | URL                   | Response                                                                                  |
|--------   |---------------------- |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   |
| GET       | /ctrl/test/5          | { "input": 5, "when": "/Date(1408041216116)/", "req": "GET", "call": "Test" }             |
| POST      | /ctrl/test/5          | { "input": 5, "when": "/Date(1408041227561)/", "req": "POST", "call": "Test" }            |
| PUT       | /ctrl/test/5          | { "input": 5, "when": "/Date(1408041252646)/", "req": "PUT", "call": "Test" }             |
| GET       | /ctrl/testgetonly/5   | { "input": 5, "when": "/Date(1408041335907)/", "req": "GET", "call": "TestGetOnly" }      |
| POST      | /ctrl/testgetonly/5   | 404                                                                                       |
| PUT       | /ctrl/testgetonly/5   | 404                                                                                       |
| GET       | /ctrl/TestPostOnly/5  | 404                                                                                       |
| POST      | /ctrl/TestPostOnly/5  | { "input": 5, "when": "/Date(1408041464096)/", "req": "POST", "call": "TestPostOnly" }    |
| PUT       | /ctrl/TestPostOnly/5  | 404                                                                                       |
| GET       | /ctrl/TestBoth/5      | 404                                                                                       |
| POST      | /ctrl/TestBoth/5      | 404                                                                                       |
| PUT       | /ctrl/TestBoth/5      | 404                                                                                       |
| GET       | /ctrl/TestVerbs/5     | { "input": 5, "when": "/Date(1408041709606)/", "req": "GET", "call": "TestVerbs" }        |
| POST      | /ctrl/TestVerbs/5     | { "input": 5, "when": "/Date(1408041831549)/", "req": "POST", "call": "TestVerbs" }       |
| PUT       | /ctrl/TestVerbs/5     | 404                                                                                       |
```

Comment: Good example. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

In Mvc 4 you can use AcceptVerbsAttribute, I think this is a very clean solution

```
[AcceptVerbs(WebRequestMethods.Http.Get, WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)]
public IHttpActionResult Login()
{
   // Login logic
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You cant combine this to attributes.

But you can put both on one action method but you can encapsulate your
logic into a other method and call this method from both actions.

The `ActionName` Attribute allows to have 2 ActionMethods with the same name.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    return MyMethodHandler();
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("MyMethod")]
public ActionResult MyMethodPost()
{
    return MyMethodHandler();
}

private ActionResult MyMethodHandler()
{
    // handle the get or post request
    return View("MyMethod");
}
```

Comment: Not sure what "You cant combine this to attributes." means, but you can combine attributes, as shown in another answer.

Comment: I tried to add [HttpGet, HttpPost] to one action, but this is not working only first attribute working, so for me this answer is correct.

Comment: [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post|HttpVerbs.Get)] works. Just tried it. However, using [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] on same action only seems to work for the first verb.

Comment: It is not incorrect because it works yet it is unnecessary as httppost and httpget can be combined using the acceptvebs as shown before