# Make Ajax call before page loads

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Before the page loads, I need to run a check on the user's security level. This will determine which elements of our nav bar they are able to see. I have tried two methods at running this ajax call, both inside the `$(document).ready` function.

(the `div` named `container` encompasses the `ul` in the html below)

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    //First attempt
    $('#container').load(
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckSecurity","Home")'
        })
    );

    //Second attempt 
    window.onload = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckSecurity","Home")'
        });
    };
});
```

Since this is an ASP MVC 3 site, I've set a breakpoint in the `CheckSecurity` method. I can tell neither call is working due to the fact it is never fired.

The controller method is listed below

```
public ActionResult CheckSecurity()
{
    ViewBag.UserName = Security.GetUserName(User);
    ViewBag.Admin = Security.IsAdmin(User);
    ViewBag.ITsupport = Security.IsItSupport(User);
    ViewBag.Read = Security.IsViewer(User);
    ViewBag.Modify = Security.IsModifier(User);
    return View();            
}
```

This is supposed to check the user's security level, place the `boolean` value in the ViewBag, and then determine whether or not to display the `Admin Features` drop down item below

```
<li class="dropdown">  
    <a href="#"  
       class="dropdown-toggle"  
       data-toggle="dropdown"
       data-hover="dropdown">  
        Admin  
        <b class="caret"></b>  
    </a>  
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
        <li>@Html.MenuLink("Products", "Index", "Product")</li>
        <li>@Html.MenuLink("Product Training", "Index", "Course")</li>
        <li>@Html.MenuLink("Continuing Ed", "Index", "ContEdCourse")</li>
        @if (ViewBag.Admin)
        {
            <li>@Html.MenuLink("Admin Features", "Index", "DropDownValues")</li>             
        }
    </ul>  
</li>
```

When the page attempts to load, it instead crashes with this error pointing to the `@if (ViewBag.Admin)` line:

`Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type`

Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated. Thx!

Comment: Do you have an element with an `id="container"`? and does that element even have a load event? (only iframes images scripts and the window have load events). the second attempt should have worked though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/**ViewBags just work in the same View**. Which means this:

If you are in

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Index
}
```

and then you execute by ajax

```
public ActionResult OtherAction()
{
    ViewBag.Other
}
```

The `ViewBag.Other` will not be visible in Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Index
    ViewBag.Other//erro other is null cuz because bellows to  OtherAction view
}
```

So, you could  return a list instead.

Comment: So basically whatever controller/method you are working in is the one that needs to set the `ViewBag`?

Comment: I'm still curious why the Ajax isn't being fired off though. Any ideas on that?

Comment: i don't see any html where you have an element with id of `container`. Are you sure the selector `$(#container)` selects any elements?

Comment: Make sure that the CheckSecurity action result is in HomeController also. And see this post, that may be causing the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767911/mvc-httppost-httpget-for-action

Comment: It is in the `HomeController`. What's odd is, since this is a shared layout page, the Ajax actually does fire when you load the site's home/index.cshtml page. However, navigate to anywhere else in the site (all pages use the same layout w/the navbar/ajax code) and the method will not get called.