# What is the advantage of adding the [HttpGet] annotation?

Tags: c#, annotations, data-annotations, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

In the event that a Controller specifies a route:

```
[Route("api/platypus/getPlatypi")]
public List<Platypus> GetAllPlatypi()
{
    return _platypusRepository.GetPlatypi();
}
```

...is there any advantage to annotating it with a "[HttpGet]" like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/platypus/getPlatypi")]
public List<Platypus> GetAllPlatypi()
{
   return _platypusRepository.GetPlatypi();
}
```

?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11767955/1470747) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example you have given there is not any advantage to adding the HTTP method attribute. By convention Web API will try to match a controller method that starts with the HTTP request method (GET, POST, PUT etc.).

In your example the method `GetAllPlatypi` will be considered for a match for all GET requests to that controller.

If however your method was named `FindAllPlatypi` you would need to add the `[HttpGet]` attribute to make it clear that this method is meant for GET requests.