# HttpPost and Authorize leads to Error: Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post

In my ASP.Net (.net 4.7 + MVC5) web application I have an action Search() which leads to the an error after authorising the user. The error is as follows:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Search
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0

The action is implemented as follows:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("Search")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModels passedQuery)
    {
      //Action working code here
      return View("~/Views/Home/Search.cshtml", passedQuery);
    }
```

Form submission code as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Content, new { @class = "form-control" })<br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
}
```

If I take the [HttpPost] out from the action then during debugging mode the application works perfectly even after authorising the user (No error thrown). But without using the [HttpPost] the code does nothing on the production server.

Can someone help with:

- Why the error message is shown when [HttpPost] is used with
  [Authroize]?
- When and why to use [HttpPost]? (I have referred to few    posts and
  documents regarding the usage of HttpPost and HttpGet but    still I
  am finding it liitle hard to grasp the concept of their
  appropriate usage [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332275/httppost-vs-httpget-attributes-in-mvc-why-use-httppost), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767911/mvc-httppost-httpget-for-action))

I am very new to ASP.Net and MVC development and any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This line which returns a view makes no sense:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Search.cshtml", passedQuery);
```

In proper usage, just use view name instead of its complete virtual path with extension and ensure that the `Search` method belongs to `HomeController`:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModels passedQuery)
    {
       return View("Search", passedQuery); // or just return View(passedQuery)
    }
}
```

Note that [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) requires authorized users who meet the specified requirements to access the method, so it's no use to set it on POST methods while submitting the form which already loaded. You need to specify `AuthorizeAttribute` on controller class when users requesting page they're wanted to view based from authentication roles, and set `AllowAnonymousAttribute` on methods which you're allow anonymous users to get through.

Hence, your `Search` action pair should constructed like this example:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // other stuff

    [Route("Search")]
    [HttpGet] // getting search page request
    [AllowAnonymous] // allow anonymous users to load search page
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost] // posting content using inserted values on form
    [AllowAnonymous] // allow anonymous users to load search page
    public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModels passedQuery)
    {
       return View("Search", passedQuery); // or just return View(passedQuery)
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i used the technique you have shared but it still threw the same error! I need to pass (SearchViewModels passedQuery) as parameter because the view requires this object to process few things. If i use 'public ActionResult Search()' with [AllowAnonymous] without passing the SearchViewModels parameter then the program throws a null exception error because the view is expecting that parameter.