# Why do I get a HTTP ERROR 404 when listing products by category using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC with pagination?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Why do I have HTTP ERROR 404?

I am trying to list products by category using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, and at the same time including a pagination to a view. I am using a  ProductsController.cs which has an Index method to display all products, and ProductsByCategory to display only the products with the same category. When I go to: https://localhost:7179/products I got: This localhost page can’t be found, HTTP ERROR 404. atm, I have two categories cacti and bouquet, and can display them when I go to: https://localhost:7179/products/cacti
I have not yest finished pagination as I have problem displaying all products view.
Category Model:

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage ="Minimum Length is 2")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only Letters are allowed")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Slug { get; set; }
        public int Sorting { get; set; }
    }
```

Products Controller:

```
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {

        private readonly FlowerShopContext context;
        public ProductsController(FlowerShopContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }


        //GET /Products/Index
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int p = 1)
        {
            int pageSize = 12;
            var products = context.Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Include(x => x.Category).Skip((p - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

            ViewBag.PageNumber = p;
            ViewBag.PageRange = pageSize;
            ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)context.Products.Count() / pageSize);

            return View(await products.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET /products/category
        public async Task<IActionResult> ProductsByCategory(string categorySlug, int p = 1)
        {
            Category category = await context.Categories.Where(x => x.Slug == categorySlug).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (category == null) return RedirectToAction("Index");

            int pageSize = 6;
            var products = context.Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                                            .Where(x => x.CategoryId == category.Id)
                                            .Skip((p - 1) * pageSize)
                                            .Take(pageSize);

            ViewBag.PageNumber = p;
            ViewBag.PageRange = pageSize;
            ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)context.Products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == category.Id).Count() / pageSize);
            ViewBag.CategoryName = category.Name;
            ViewBag.CategorySlug = categorySlug;

            return View(await products.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "All Products";
    }


<h1>All Products</h1>


<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="~/media/products/@item.Image" class="image-fluid" width="250" alt=""/>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>
                @Html.Raw(item.Description)
            </div>
            <p>@item.Price.ToString("c2")</p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add to cart</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

ProductsByCategory.cshtml View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Products by category";
    }


<h1>Products by category</h1>


<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="~/media/products/@item.Image" class="image-fluid" width="250" alt=""/>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>
                @Html.Raw(item.Description)
            </div>
            <p>@item.Price.ToString("c2")</p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add to cart</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Program.cs  endpoints:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      "pages",
      "{slug?}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "Page" }
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "products-category",
        "products/{categorySlug}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "ProductsByCategory" }
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 
});
```

FlowerShopContext.cs

```
   public class FlowerShopContext : DbContext
    {
        public FlowerShopContext(DbContextOptions<FlowerShopContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: your code is not problem,can you send FlowerShopContext with text

Comment: the attributes being sent by the request is not matching what is expected in the server which causes the 404 error path is not found.  See following to help debug and understand better what is happening : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713510/get-the-attribute-tag-from-a-controller-method-in-mvc  In your case the route is not matching.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does only products  route getting the 404 or all of your routes? While running in dev environment does product route works?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron  just products, to be more precise Index.cshtml View from ProductsController.cs,

Comment: @jdweng  I still cant pinpoint where is the problem.  I understand that bad routing causing this, but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi Is ok to paste as a text FlowerShopContext.cs here in comments?  I just started using StackOverflow so I do not know atm all of the guidelines.

Comment: please edit this your Post(  add FlowerShopContext in this your Post)

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi just added FlowerShopContext.cs to a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you concentrate on the Index and perhaps the List  ? it returns. Get that working then figure out the filter by Category part. - Show the Product class; I assume Product has a Category object or a List Categories  if they can have multiple? Try to make things obvious to your 5 years from now self who maintains it and use good names like Index(int page = 1)

Study routing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/")]
    [Route("/Home")]
    [Route("~/Home/Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo();
    }

    [Route("/products/{page}")]
    public IActionResult ListAProducts(int page)
    {
        return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo(page);
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo();
    }
}
```

Notice I don't put anything in the ViewBag?  Create a pagination object you can put in your "Page" object which contains your Pagination and `List<Products>` perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I see that, there is a `Products Controller`, with `Index` method and it takes a Parameter `int p = 1`.
But in your `Program.cs` endpoints, there is no matching `Route`, which points to `Products/Index/Id`.

Hence I think that is causing the Issue.

Comment: Parameter int p = 1 is only used for pagination, so the pagination starts from 1, not 0. Index method should get all of the products from database, not only one and that is why I did not use Id or make any routes Products/Index/Id

Comment: What am I trying to say is, there is Home/Index route and no Product/Index route.